# Fiware: data privacy generic enabler implementation?

Tags: fiware

Is there an implemented generic enabler for data privacy?
I founded the [sepcifications](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/FIWARE.ArchitectureDescription.Security.Privacy) but can't found an implementation.

Thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reference implementation is on github at https://github.com/zhaw-munt/p2abcengine/releases . The current release is for FIWARE sprint 4.4.3.

Please note that funding for this enabler has been removed, and that the enabler is in maintenance mode, with end-of-life projected for December 2016.

Cheers,

Stephan